# Cost or price... for a thing at a retailer

Tags: difference

Do we pay 'price' of a book or 'cost' of a book **as a customer** ***at a retailer***?

A good dictionary though mentions the difference between the two, in this way.

> Cost = the amount of money that you need in order to buy, make or do
>   something

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cost_1?q=cost

> Price = the amount of money that you have to pay for something

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/price_1?q=price

Answer (score 2):

From your point of view, in relation to the retailer, they are the same thing.

---

From the point of view of the retailer **in relation to you**:

> cost = the money they paid (to their supplier) to buy the good
>
> price = the money they ask from you in exchange for the good

---

From the point of view of the retailer **in relation to their supplier**, again, the two words have the same meaning.

---

In a pseudo-scientific way:

> price = cost + taxes + profit (+ ...)

Also, from a different point of view, as noticed by @J.R., the following equation is also true:

> cost = price + taxes

---

With different words:

> The PRICE set by the SELLER = the COST supported by the BUYER

Comment: My pseudo-scientific equation would be a little different than yours; I'd say `cost = price + taxes`, where the _price_ is what the retailer puts on the price tag, but the _cost_ is what I actually pay at the register. That said, I am in complete agreement with your larger point, that the two words are generally regarded as synonymous, and we don't typically try to delineate any differences between the two.

Comment: @J.R.: you are right also. The two concepts transform into each other with different equations, depending on the context and the point of view. +1

Comment: In a retail or wholesale transaction, the buyer commonly pays the price of something. It is, to the buyer, a cost.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: that is exactly what I said with the last equation.